# Overlapping atomic radii in data of experimentally observed protein assemblies

Tags: molecular-biology, protein-structure

I am looking at experimentally observed configurations of viral capsid proteins like that of the tobacco mosaic virus. https://www.rcsb.org/structure/6R7M

When taking the atom centers of a monomer and applying the transformations specified in the .pdb file, I get a structure where the VDW radii of different proteins overlap. I have tested a variety of sets of radii and it happens for all of them. I tested with Bondis radii, ProtOr radii and several radii taken from popular force fields (AMBER, PARSE, CHARMM).

I am wondering:

- What is the least wrong set of radii to choose here and why?
- Is there a popular way to resolve this?
- The Clashscore depends on overlaps **within** a protein right? What radii are chosen for this measure?

Thank you in advance

Ivan

Comment: can you give us the chain ID, residue number, and atomID for the atoms in the .pdb file that are overlapping in the linked TMV structure? Is this something you've noticed in other structures as well, or just this one?

Comment: In the example behind the link, the chain ID is 'A' and considering two adjacent monomers transformed by the specified BIOMTs we get an overlap between Atom IDs 164 and 72 by 0.3 Angström for example, when choosing Bondis VDW radii for the atoms. There are around 20 of these overlaps in total. 

So far every assembled TMV structure I checked has these overlaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [validation report for model 6R7M](https://files.rcsb.org/pub/pdb/validation_reports/r7/6r7m/6r7m_full_validation.pdf), we see that there are no symmetry-related clashes listed. (Although there are two clashes within the asymmetric unit, HA of ASP20 - HD3 of PRO21 and HG13 of ILE95 - HB2 of ALA111)
The relevant portion of the PDB's validation explanation page is [here](https://www.wwpdb.org/validation/XrayValidationReportHelp#close_contacts):

> All-atom contacts within the ASU are calculated by the Reduce and Probe programs within MolProbity (Word et al., 1999; Chen et al., 2010). This method was developed to quantify the detailed non-covalent fit of atomic interactions within or between molecules (H-bonds, favorable van der Waals, and steric clashes). Since most such interactions involve H atoms on one or both sides, all hydrogens must be present or added (Reduce optimizes rotation of OH, SH, NH3, etc. within H-bond networks, but methyls stay staggered). At present, in order to ensure comparable scores between NMR and X-ray, hydrogen atoms are removed from the analysed structure, and replaced by a different set placed by Reduce in idealised and optimized nuclear-H positions. **All-atom unfavorable overlaps ≥0.4Å are then identified as clashes**, using van der Waals radii tuned for the nuclear H positions suitable for NMR (rather than the electron-cloud H positions suitable for X-ray).).

(bolding mine)

The main takeaway is that MolProbity does not consider that amount of overlap to be a problem. So to your second bullet point, I don't think anything needs to be resolved.
As for which radii should be used, I don't have good advice. It looks like that [is still being debated](https://chemistry-europe.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cphc.201901083). However, looking up [the original paper for the MolProbity tools](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022283698924007?via%3Dihub) used by the PDB for validation, the radii for O and non-carbonyl C are 1.4 and 1.75 Angströms, respectively. That sums to 3.15, I measure 2.92 between the atomic centers, so slightly less overlap than you got.
My initial assumption was that these would be poorly-resolved residues near the edge of the macromolecule and that the VDW overlap would be due to fitting errors, but it looks pretty good to me:
[image: The atomic model of PDB6R7M is shown fitted into the density map EMD4628]